# Error during string matching?

Tags: c#

I am trying to catch and exception message as below and running into below errors,can anyone provided inputs on how to fix this?is there a better way to handle string matching?

```
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ////catch
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("Reading from the stream has failed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                }
      }
```

> Error  1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>
> Error  2   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error  3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.StringComparison' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' C:\Users\gnakkala\gnakkala_dashboard\source\qcom\qca\wconnect\wbit\automation\Dashboard\sandbox\Dashboard.Data.Repository\BuildRepositories\LookaheadGerritsRepository.cs

Comment: You should learn more about structured exception handling.  Trying to parse an error message is not really the right way to go about it when you have other more robust methods available.

Comment: @weston: Actually, the `Message.Contains(...)` call is the code that causes the problem.

Comment: @SamAxe - what  is the robust method you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `string.Contains()` method that takes a `StringComparison`. Most people end up using an `IndexOf()` call for this purpose.

Comment: Warrior -  please advise what method to use for string comparison

Comment: @JeffShort: Did you look at the answer to the question I marked this as a duplicate of? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/120955

Comment: I saw that and I am using the same... .`.contains`

Comment: @JeffShort: [One good way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444818/120955) is to use `.IndexOf("Reading from the stream has failed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`